# Handling conditions within smart pointer custom deleters

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I have a unique pointer with a custom deleter provided as a lambda function. Within lambda function I need to handle 2 scenarios. If exception occurs do one thing and if not do other thing. What is the best way to know an exception occurred inside lambda function?

```
    void f()
    {
        //start a transaction
        std::unique_ptr<Transaction> transactionOb(new Transaction(),[](Transaction* transaction)
        {
          if(exception occurred)
                {
                  transaction->rollback()
                }
                else
                {
                  transaction->commit()
                }
        });

        try
        {
           //write data to database
        }
        catch()
        {
          //handle exception
        }
    }
```

Comment: This feels a bit like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you elaborate about *why* you think you need to do this, you may be presented with a better solution.

Comment: What exception? Which function does throw an exception?

Comment: There is no way to determine what causes an object's lifetime to end.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `transactionOb` doesn't hand off it's `Transaction` to somewhere else, you can reference capture some local state, and set it to a different value in your `catch`

```
void f()
{
    bool didExcept = false;
    //start a transaction
    std::unique_ptr<Transaction> transactionOb(new Transaction(),[&didExcept](Transaction* transaction)
    {
        if(didExcept)
        {
            transaction->rollback()
        }
        else
        {
            transaction->commit()
        }
        // Missing delete transaction
    });

    try
    {
       //write data to database
    }
    catch()
    {
        didExcept = true;
      //handle exception
    }
}
```

Or alternatively you can rollback in the `catch`, and unset the pointer.

```
void f()
{
    //start a transaction
    std::unique_ptr<Transaction> transactionOb(new Transaction(),[](Transaction* transaction)
    {
        if(transaction)
        {
            transaction->commit()
        }
        delete transaction;
    });

    try
    {
       //write data to database
    }
    catch()
    {
        transactionOb->rollback();
        delete transactionOb.release();
      //handle exception
    }
}
```